# Validar una URL con PHP

Tags: php, url

Tengo una gran duda de sobre como puedo validar una URL desde PHP pero que, además, ésta tenga protocolo https o de lo contrario sea incorrecta.

Basándome en esto podría decir si una URL es válida:

**Codigo:**

```
<?php
    // Variable to check
    $url = "http://www.w3schools.com/";

    // Remover los caracteres ilegales de la url
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    echo $url;
    // Validar url
    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        echo("$url es una URL valida");
    } else {
        echo("$url no es una URL valida");
    }
    ?>
```

Ahora solo debo saber si tiene el protocolo https.

Comment: Sería interesante que dijeras en tu pregunta el uso que quieres darle... si es para redirigir, o sea, para forzar a que se acceda a tu página sólo a través de https sería mejor usar .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esto PHP ya trae una función nativa, `parse_url`.

```
$url = "http://www.w3schools.com/";

$urlparts= parse_url($url);

$scheme = $urlparts['scheme'];

if ($scheme === 'https') {
    echo("$url es una URL valida");
} else {
    echo("$url no es una URL valida");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso debes usar lo siguiente

```
$urls = array('http://www.website.com', 'https://www.website.com', 'http://website.com', 'https://website.com', 'www.website.com', 'website.com');
foreach($urls as $url) {
    if (preg_match('#^(https?://|www\.)#i', $url) === 1){
        echo $url . ' matches' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $url . ' fails' . "\n";
    }
```

Salida:

```
http://www.website.com matches
https://www.website.com matches
http://website.com matches
https://website.com matches
www.website.com matches
website.com fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Si queremos comprobar por PHP si navegamos a través de protocolo seguro o no utilizaríamos la siguiente condición:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    // Codigo a ejecutar si se navega bajo entorno seguro.
} else {
    // Codigo a ejecutar si NO se navega bajo entorno seguro.
}
```

Comment: gracias por comentar, yo lo que quiero saber es por ejemplo: recibo una cadena que es una url y la quiero validar para saber si esta tiene https, encontre algo sobre validar la cadena con expresion  regular pero no desearia usarla si es posible

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, no se trata de averiguar si el script actual se encuentra ejecutándose en https o no.